# Is there a std::includes equivalent for unsorted ranges?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

`std::includes` is [documented as](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/includes)

> Returns true if every element from **the sorted range** [first2, last2) is
>   found within **the sorted range** [first1, last1). Also returns true if
>   [first2, last2) is empty.

The emphasis is mine.

Is there an equivalent C++ algorithm that reproduces this functionality on an unsorted range from a container, or do I have to go back to implementing this myself via loops?

Comment: sort the range first?

Comment: One of the ranges is sorted on another property other than what I want to use `includes` on, so I'd need to create a second container just in order to sort it, either temporarily or have to maintain alignment of the contents of the two.

Comment: I guess you can write `std::all_of(first2, last2, [&](const auto& e) { return std::find(first1, last1, e) != last1; })`, but it's O(MN).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you sort the range first, the sort will run in O(*n* log *n*) time and the search will run in O(*m*+*n*) time.  If you try to do this naïvely on an unsorted range, it will run in O(*m*·*n*) time.  You’re *usually* better off just sorting.

You can, however, `search` an unsorted range for a substring efficiently.  That’s the closest thing I can think of to what you’re asking for.

Comment: Which one is better rather depends on the relative size of `m` and `n`, no?

Comment: Sure, but if you’re searching for a single element, you can just use `std::find`, and if *m* is small, you can `std::find` each one and break as soon as one isn’t found.  So that’s how you can do it on an unsorted range in O(*mn*) time with STL if that’s better than O(*n* log *n*).  (It might not be as efficient in real-world use due to locality of reference.)

Comment: But I added a weasel word.